# How to show list of field values of a collection of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api

---

I am making an API that shows a collection of ads with MongoDB and Node.js

I need to display the list of collection tags in a JSON string.

Example: 'home', 'mobile', 'motor'

This is the API initializer code:

```
const readline = require('readline');


const Product = require('./models/Product');

async function main() {

  const advance = await question('Are you sure to continue with the deletion of the database? (yes or no) ')
  if (!advance) {
    process.exit();
  }

  const connection = require('./lib/connectMongoose')

  await initProducts();

  connection.close();
}

async function initProducts() {
  const deleted = await Product.deleteMany();
  console.log(`Remove ${deleted.deletedCount} products.`);

  const inserted = await Product.insertMany([
    {name: 'Table', sale: true, price: 150, photo: 'Table.png', tags: ['home']},
    {name: 'Iphone 13 pro', sale: false, price: 950, photo: 'Iphone 13 pro.png', tags: ['mobile']},
    {name: 'Car Mini Cooper', sale: true, price: 1000, photo: 'Car Mini Cooper.png', tags: ['motor']}
  ]);

  console.log(`Create ${inserted.length} products.`)

}

main().catch(err => console.log('Hubo un error', err))

function question(text) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const interface = readline.createInterface({
      input: process.stdin,
      output: process.stdout
    });
    interface.question(text, answer => {
      interface.close();
      if (answer.toLowerCase() === 'yes') {
        resolve(true);
        return;
      }
      resolve(false);
    })
  })
}
```

I need to find a MongoDB method that allows me to show when the API route calls the list that shows in JSON format all the tags that the collection includes

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly, one option is `$unwind` the `tags` array to get all tags as strings and be able to `$group` adding to a set to avoid duplicates.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$tags"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "tags": {
        "$addToSet": "$tags"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

I think this works but `$unwind` and `$group` the entire collection is not always a good idea. It may be a slow process.

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yz8Ft03AEN8)

Comment: But I understand that this is a method to filter the tags with mongoDB, right? How could I take it to Node.js so that when calling the API the values of the tags are displayed?

Comment: The same way you do `await Product.deleteMany()` you can use `await Product.aggregate([{/*...*/}])` and use the query. Where? It depends on your project, you need a controller which accepts the HTTP petition and handle it there. But that's another question I think.

Comment: I applied your solution but it doesn't work for me

Comment: What’s the problem? Not the expected output?